# A better formatting help

Tags: feature-request, markdown, documentation

Some people is not able to understand the key concepts of formatting in SO (and all other sites).
I would suggest to improve the [default formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) with some features, like:

1. Explain the **basic concept** of formatting. Something like:

   > When you make posts, you are given a text area in which you write *plain, unformatted* text.
   >   Below this area is a dotted frame. It shows **how will your post look** when you submit it.
   >
   > Start by writing some text. You will see how the frame updates to reflect the changes.
   >   Now, let's go further. Formatting your posts is easy!
2. Then, teach the user with some basic examples:

   > We'll start with something simple. Imagine you want to highlight some words of your message.
   >   Write the following text in the source area:
   >
   > ```
   > The last word of this message is **highlighted**.
   > ```
   >
   > Then look at the preview. Voila! The word between `**` and `**` is highlighted in bold.
   >   Similary, to put some text in *italic*, write it between `_` and `_`.
3. Go further with the **code blocks**, **code snaps** and **quotes**.
4. Refer a link to the original formatting help page for more advanced info,
   and include images showing the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it would help a lot more if there's some header like **Question Preview** on top of the preview area so that it's more clear to them what it represents. If necessary with a thiny footer like

*<sub>If your code does not appear correctly in preview, ensure that you have applied code formatting [insert detailed explanation]</sub>*.

Apply this on both the Ask Question and Edit screens.

Comment: Yes, this would make things more intuitive. We can also put the explanation in a dedicated page, so to send links to the page.